# Visual Studio C++ 2015 Program Builds and Opens Console Window But No Output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have written a simple hello world program in c++ to make sure it wasn't a programming error that was causing my difficulties. If you would like to check over the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello, World\n";
std::cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Anyways, when I open up a program that I made months ago. (I recently started learning again) and run that program it outputs as should. When creating a new program from scratch the program builds and opens up a console window but remains at a blank screen. I believe this is the fault of the IDE and I am missing a setting somewhere.

New Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello, World\n";
std::cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Ctrl+F5:
[Blank Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZjZ3.png)

Old Program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int doubleNumber(int x) {
return x * 2;
}
int main()
{   
std::cout << "Starting Main" << std::endl;
int y;
std::cout << "Please enter a value you would like to double: ";
std::cin >> y;
y = doubleNumber(y);
std::cout << y << std::endl;
std::cout << "Ending Main" << std::endl;
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Ctrl+F5:
[Console as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tPNH.png)

This problem occurs in all cases of the old and new programs. The programs that I have written today do not display anything to the console, but the programs that I have written in the past perform as inteded.

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: I do indeed, i disabled it and it fixed my problem. Thanks boss.

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` will flush the buffered output to the console.  The old programs use that.  Your 'today' programs do not, so their output is still in the output buffers.  Replace your `"\n"` in your strings with `std::endl`.

Comment: I have made this addition to the program and it still gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to disable avast antivirus. As simple as this sounds, it is indeed the solution. If you are having this problem I would recommend disabling your antivirus as well.

Comment: You don't need to completely disable your antivirus, you can add an exclusion for your "\Visual Studio 2015\Projects" folder.